# git push keeps adding weird username@IPaddress in commit

Tags: git

whenever I do a git commit/push my branch and then when the auto merge fails I see:

```
Sending e-mails to: DL@email.com MYUSERNAME@COMPANY.com MYUSERNAME@192.168.29.215 
ERROR: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 24BAB460FCE
```

I checked my got config both system & global level and everything looks fine. Where is this MYUSERNAME@192.168.29.215 getting added and how do I fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your git config output

Comment: `git push` does not perform any merging. What is this auto-merge you speak of? That must be done by something else.

Comment: ya merging isnt the concern I am just wondering where this MYUSERNAME@192.168.29.215 is coming from. I dont see anywhere in my git config

Answer (score 1):

> I am just wondering where this `MYUSERNAME@192.168.29.215` is coming from. I dont see anywhere in my git config

That would be the default user.name used by Git when `user.name` is not set.

If you set your username (used for commit authorship) in your git config, you won't see that anymore.

```
git config --global user.name my_name
```